# Rstem and sentiment package installation issue

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis

It seems without `Rstem` and `sentiment` packages twitter sentiment analysis
is difficult. 
I am trying this `Rstem` and sentiment packages installation using the tar.gz file
(as no windows binary available in omegahat or in the github of Timothy P. Jurka) 
but it gives an error:

> installation of package 'Rstem' had non-zero exit status

I tried even command prompt. That gives below error. Any clue how to solve it ? my system is windows 7, R 2.15, Rstudio.

```
    D:\R Projects>R CMD INSTALL Rstem_0.4-1.tar.gz
* installing to library 'D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/library'
* installing *source* package 'Rstem' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:194: warning: overriding recipe for
 target `.m.o'
D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:187: warning: ignoring old recipe f
or target `.m.o'
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c api.c -o api.o
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c danish_stem.c -o danish_stem.o
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c dutch_stem.c -o dutch_stem.o
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c english_stem.c -o english_stem.o
english_stem.c: In function 'r_prelude':
english_stem.c:376:5: warning: label 'lab1' defined but not used
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c finnish_stem.c -o finnish_stem.o
finnish_stem.c: In function 'r_case':
finnish_stem.c:448:21: warning: unused variable 'm'
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c french_stem.c -o french_stem.o
french_stem.c: In function 'french_stem':
french_stem.c:951:25: warning: unused variable 'm'
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c german_stem.c -o german_stem.o
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c mytest.c -o mytest.o
mytest.c: In function 'S_stemWords':
mytest.c:76:3: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'Rf_mkChar' dif
fer in signedness
D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include/Rinternals.h:628:6: note: expected 'const cha
r *' but argument is of type 'symbol *'
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c norwegian_stem.c -o norwegian_stem.o
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c portuguese_stem.c -o portuguese_stem.o
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c russian_stem.c -o russian_stem.o
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c spanish_stem.c -o spanish_stem.o
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c swedish_stem.c -o swedish_stem.o
gcc  -I"D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I../Snowball/q
 -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c utilities.c -o utilities.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, basename Rstem.dll .dll, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, basename Rstem.dll .dll, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, basename Rstem.dll .dll, ...) failed.
"zapi.o danish_stem.o dutch_stem.o english_stem.o finnish_stem.o french_stem.o g
erman_stem.o mytest.o norwegian_stem.o portuguese_stem.o russian_stem.o spanish_
stem.o swedish_stem.o utilities.o" was unexpected at this time.
make: *** [Rstem.dll] Error 255
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Rstem'
* removing 'D:/R-Econometrics/R-2.15.1/library/Rstem'
```

Comment: Finally,I got the windows binaries at below places:

Comment: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/Rstem_0.4-1.zip

Comment: http://cms.unipune.ernet.in/~webmaster/cran/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/sentiment_0.2.zip

Comment: But the Rstem at stats.ox.ac.uk is only for 32 bit windows! so now I have to look for 64 bit

Comment: Mac OS X binary is at https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rstem/